# Search Query by Child field Eloquent relation

Tags: laravel, join, eloquent, relation

My Product Model is

```
public function IncomeRepo(){

        return $this->hasMany(Income::class,'Product');
    }
```

My Income Report Model Is

```
 public function ProductData(){
        
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class,'Product','id');
    }
```

My Query is

```
public function SearchIncomeData(Request $request){

    $GetFromDate = $request->FromDate;
    $GetToDate = $request->ToDate;
        
        $ProductData = Product::with('IncomeRepo')->whereBetween('created_at', [$GetFromDate, $GetToDate])->get();
        
       return view('Admin.Report.ProductSalesReport',compact('ProductData'));

 }
```

When I return `$ProductData`  it return products table `created_at`  Data. BUT I nee Income table created_at data which be multiple

How can I get it?

My expectation show incomes table `created_at` data

Comment: "When I return $ProductData it return variable it return products table created_at BUT I nee Income table created_at data which be multiple", can you explain that one a bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In controller**. (Use `whereBetween`)

```
public function SearchIncomeData(Request $request)
{
    $GetFromDate = $request->FromDate;
    $GetToDate = $request->ToDate;

    $ProductData = Product::with(['IncomeRepo' => function ($query) use ($GetFromDate, $GetToDate)
    {
        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$GetFromDate, $GetToDate]);
    }
    ])->get();

    return view('Admin.Report.ProductSalesReport', compact('ProductData'));
}
```

**In view**

```
foreach ($ProductData as $product)
{
    foreach ($product->IncomeRepo as $income)
    {
        echo $income->created_at;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter data by child tables date then you need to use whereHas relationship.

```
$GetFromDate = $request->FromDate;
$GetToDate = $request->ToDate;
    
$ProductData = Product::with('IncomeRepo')
           ->whereHas('IncomeRepo',function($que) use($GetFromDate,$GetToDate) { 
           $que->whereBetween('created_at',[$GetFromDate, $GetToDate])})->get();
    
return view('Admin.Report.ProductSalesReport',compact('ProductData'));
```